# Custom spinner style

Tags: android-layout, android

How can I style/customize spinner like shown below using xml?
I can make white background with border, but i can't set icon on the left and arrow on the right.

[image]

Comment: Create a xml layout similar to this. And use the View Holder Adapter approach. Its simple.

Comment: Is the icon on the left specific to each spinner item or is it static spinner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is with a layout that sets the icon to the left and arrow to the right, the following should work.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm at work, so I can't test this out, but I think it should work.